# Streaming video from Android device to PC using libstreaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream a video from an Android device to a PC by using the [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library. To connect the two devices I open a Hotspot on the Android device and connect the PC to it.

I tried the [examples 1 and 2](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples) and got them running. With example 2 I receive a lot of UDP packets in Wireshark. But I am not able to open the stream in VLC Player. With example 1 I get nothing in Wireshark.

Can anybody tell me what I have to type in VLC to open the stream? I tried a lot of different things, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. For example 1 I think it has to be something like rtsp://ipofandroiddevice:port

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the libstreaming library, but it looks like it sends RTP packets to an address.

In this case you should only open: rtp://@:port on your computer to get the video.
Just be aware of NAT issues if you are streaming from outside an internal network.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but it didn't work. I'm sure about the port because I can see the destination port in Wireshark. I think the problem may be somewhere else. Maybe there is a problem with the codec of the video or something similar.

Comment: Did you try open vlc with -vvv flag? You should be able to see if it's seeing packets and in general live555 logs

Comment: Now I'm sure it isn't a problem with vlc. I created a simple Android application that permanently sends UDP packets with the datagramSocket class. I also wrote a small java application that just writes the received packets on the console. Again I'm able to see the packets in Wireshark but my server doesn't receive anything. Maybe the ports I'm using are blocked by a firewall. But would I be able to receive packets with Wireshark even if the ports are blocked?

Answer (score 0):

The RTSP URL you posted in your question is missing some parameters, it should be something like,

**rtsp://phone_local_ip:1234?*h264=200-20-320-240***

200 = buf | 20 = fps | 320 = width | 240 = height

There is a UriParser class in the library, you might need to check it our for other possible URL formats.

Comment: I'm using `rtsp://172.xx.xx.67:1777?h264=500000-15-640-480`: log on android stream server: OPTIONS 200 -> DESCRIBE 200 -> SETUP 200 -> PLAY 200 -> TEARDOWN 200 -> Error parsing CSeq (IllegalStateException: No successful match so far) - no method in the request

Comment: Not sure as I didn't face this issue. A few suggestions, try reducing the buffer to really 200. Somehow for me other resolution didn't work other than 320-240. Even though the other ones were in list of supported resolutions.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will try your suggestion shortly. Fully my issue discarded [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287579/stream-using-libstreaming-to-vlc-exception).

Comment: unfortunately I didn't make it to work :( Official example has the same issue. Maybe new version of library has some mistakes. Could you provide your old version of **libstreaming**? I want to try it.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk hmm.. Sorry I don't have any older code, just the recent version. Though it is github right, you can checkout some older commit if you really need the older code.