# Stream using libstreaming to VLC 2.2.4 exception

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, vlc, libstreaming

I setup **[libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)** to stream video from Android camera to [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) 2.2.4 on my macOS.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(1777));
editor.apply();

SessionBuilder.getInstance()
                .setContext(context)
                .setCallback(this)
                .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
                .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
                .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(640, 480, 15, 500000));

context.startService(new Intent(context, RtspServer.class));
```

Then I builded url bellow and opened it in VLC 2.2.4:

```
rtsp://172.xx.xx.67:1777?h264=500000-15-640-480
```

Then I received some logs on Android side:

```
OPTIONS
RTSP/1.0 200 OK                                                    
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Cseq: 2
Content-Length: 0  

DESCRIBE
SPS: Z0KAHtoCgPaAbQoTUA==
PPS: aM4G4g==
RTSP/1.0 200 OK                                                    
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Cseq: 3
Content-Length: 272
Content-Base: 172.xx.xx.53:1777/
Content-Type: application/sdp


v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 172.xx.xx.53
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 172.xx.xx.26
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42801e;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAHtoCgPaAbQoTUA==,aM4G4g==;
a=control:trackID=1

SETUP
PPS: aM4G4g==
SPS: Z0KAHtoCgPaAbQoTUA==
RTSP/1.0 200 
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP 
Cseq: 4
Content-Length: 0
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;destination=172.xx.xx.26;client_port=5006-5007;server_port=42104-42497;ssrc=68db94da;mode=play
Session: 1185d20035702ca
Cache-Control: no-cache

PLAY
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Cseq: 5
Content-Length: 0
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://172.xx.xx.53:1777/trackID=1;seq=0
Session: 1185d20035702ca

TEARDOWN
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Cseq: 6
Content-Length: 0

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:471)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:579)
at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspServer$Request.parseRequest(RtspServer.java:643)
at net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspServer$WorkerThread.run(RtspServer.java:393)
E/RtspServer:Error parsing CSeq: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.HashMap net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspServer$Request.headers' on a null object reference
RTSP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: MajorKernelPanic RTSP Server
Content-Length: 0
```

Or shortly:

```
OPTIONS 200 -> DESCRIBE 200 -> SETUP 200 -> PLAY 200 -> TEARDOWN 200 
-> Error parsing CSeq (IllegalStateException: No successful match so far) 
- no method in the request
```

After successful connect (all steps above) I get exception in **[RtspServer](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/rtsp/RtspServer.java)**.
As result I can't play the stream.

---

Here is the log for official example [spydroid-ipcamera](https://github.com/fyhertz/spydroid-ipcamera) (connecting from VLC 2.2.4):
[image]

---

**!!! It works on [VLC 1.1.5](https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/1.1.5/):**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Similar issues you can find [here](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples/issues/14) and [here](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/issues/166).

Comment: Now I face with "green" problem.